# API version of outbound messages

Tags: soap-api, integration, workflowoutboundmessage

I have created one outbound message just now, it will get created in API version 35, then I want it to be used after one year, this API version will be deprecated. I have used this in a package and this makes a API call in different system hence after one year it will not work. I need to change the API version of this outbound message to make it work. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

If you create managed package, you will be able to update your package.

Comment: I can update the package but the outbound message will have the same version hence it will not solve my issue